# Make two function calls run synchronously when 1 makes http GET

Tags: node.js, promise

I'm trying to make several function calls which will aggregate information and then act upon that info. Some calls make HTTP requests, which are slow. Others are much faster.

All my function calls work and build the necessary data, but I need to wait on the HTTP request before moving forward.

I've tried promises, async/await etc.

```
const http = require('http');

async function operation() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      const url = 'http://www.google.com';
      http.get(url, (resp) => {
        let data = '';
        resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
          data += chunk;
        });
        resp.on('end', () => {
          resolve(resp.statusCode);
        });
      }).on("error", (err) => {
        reject(err);
      });
    })
}

async function app() {
    var a = await operation()
    console.log('a: ', a) // this returns 200
}

function test() {
  console.log('test: ','THIS SHOULD COME AFTER')
}


app()
test()
```

I need the result of the `test` function to come after `app`. I'm seeing "THIS SHOULD COME AFTER" print before the 200

Comment: `app` is asynchronous and `test` is synchronous, according to your original design. `test` will always complete before `app`. Is there a reason you call the two functions this way? Are there reasons why you could not call `test` from within the `app` function after `await operation()`?

Comment: I don't want to do that because in my real case I have 5-10 `app` functions thats aggregate information. I then need to do work on the aggregated information. Is it possible to make the `app` function synchronous? I've tried but every time the return is a pending promise, not the actual value from the HTTP get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, `app` is an asynchronous function whereas test is synchronous. This means if you call `app(); test();` `test` will always complete before `app` resolves. However, keep in mind that `Promises` will eventually `resolve` or `reject`.

This means, to call the synchronous function after the asynchronous, you either need to call `test` within `app`, like so:

```
async function app() {
  //add try-catch to handle rejection of promise
  try {
    var a = await operation()
    console.log('a: ', a) // this returns 200
    // now you can call test after app
    test();
  } catch (err) {
    //handle error case to trigger rejection of promise
    throw new Error(err)
  }
}
```

or, remember that `Promises` are `thenable`:

```
app()
.then(someReturnedValue => test())
.catch(err => /*handle errors*/)
```

You mention in the comments you have several `app` -like functions that will be aggregated before `test`. You could consider using `Promise.all`, which takes in an array of `Promises` and will return an array of data corresponding to each resolved Promise or catch an error if any of the Promises reject.

```
Promise.all([app, app1, app2])
.then(arrayOfReturnedValues => test())
.catch(err => /*handle errors*/)
```